# SSRS 2208: Export to excel assign Cell Name

Tags: ssrs-2008

Using SSRS 2008 Environment, when exporting to Excel i want the name of the cell assigned. 
How can i achieve this?

Ex: When you open excel and click on the cell, we see name of each and every cell being A1 or A2 and so on. what if i want to change the name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what you're planning on using the cell names for?  Do you want the cells to have 'Defined Names' or do you want to see the names in the cell Name/Value in the top bar?

One of the things you should do is to name every item in the report in Properties > Name.  I'm not sure if you export to XML, but if you do you can set the Data Element names.  I haven't been able to assign defined names to all my cells, but I got most of them. Let me know if that helps, thanks.